# Stop JavaScript panel in Chrome from persisting?

Tags: google-chrome

I have a JavaScript panel in Chrome which is open when I open up the dev tools (see screenshot). I cant see how to remove this pane, is there a way?

[image]

Comment: have you tried pressing ESC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press `ESC` or click on the top right corner (3 dots menu) > `Hide Console`.